# Row and Cell Number of a selected/modified cell of DataGrid in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datagridview, cell

In C# .NET, when I edit a cell in a data grid (CellEditEnd Event maybe), how do I obtain the row and column number of the cell that I modified?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAll" runat="server"

    AutoGenerateColumns = "false" Font-Names = "Arial"

    Font-Size = "11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#C2D69B" 

    HeaderStyle-BackColor = "green" AllowPaging ="true"  

    OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging" DataKeyNames = "CustomerID"

    PageSize = "10" >

   <Columns>

    <asp:TemplateField>

        <HeaderTemplate>

            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server"

             onclick = "checkAll(this);" />

        </HeaderTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server"

             onclick = "Check_Click(this)"/>

        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField = "ContactName"

       HeaderText = "Contact Name"/>

    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField = "Country"

       HeaderText = "Country"/>

    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField = "City"

       HeaderText = "City"/>

   </Columns>

   <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#C2D69B"  />

</asp:GridView>
```

**The SetData method is called up in the OnPageIndexChanging event of the ASP.Net GridView in the following way**

```
protected void OnPaging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)

{

    gvAll.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

    gvAll.DataBind();

    SetData();

}
```

This url describe in detail

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Select-and-delete-multiple-rows-in-ASP.Net-Gridview-control.aspx